# Preventing negative values in jSpinner

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jspinner, changelistener

I am using netbeans to build gui application in java.  It has a jSpinner. I set its minimum value to 0.  When i run and click on the down arrow button, i am getting, negativearraysizeexception.  Any solution to this?

//This code is autogenerated in netbeans

```
protected void fireStateChanged() {
    Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
    for (int i = listeners.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
        if (listeners[i] == ChangeListener.class) {
            if (changeEvent == null) {
                changeEvent = new ChangeEvent(this);
            }
            ((ChangeListener)listeners[i+1]).stateChanged(changeEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code. Precisely...code inside of listener.

Comment: And the complete stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way instead of that NetBeans autogenerated code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Spinner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Spinner demo");
               //10 is init value, 0 is minimum, 20 maximum and 1 is step
                SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(10, 0, 20, 1);
                JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
                spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        JSpinner s = (JSpinner)e.getSource();
                        int val = (int)s.getValue();
                        System.out.println(val);
                    }
                });

                frame.add(spinner);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It returns proper values. No negative. Good luck!

Comment: First try, and than accept answer...No need to rush! You are welcome btw.

Answer (score 4):

it's a bit late, but here is a solution in Netbeans with auto generated code:
jSpinner -> properties -> second row "model" click [..] and u have different options :)